# What game is being represented from 2006 in this 'Evolution of Videogames' video?

Tags: game-identification

I was on Facebook and saw a video that represented the evolution of video games from 1957 to 2015.  I knew most of them (even the 1957 one), but the one that intrigued me the most that I didn't know was the game for 2006.  The HUD of the game looked so familiar to me, but I couldn't put a name to it which is why I'm asking this question.

Here's a screenshot of part of the video:

[image: 2006 game]

Here is a [link](https://youtu.be/WYJoaVMzQYc?t=2m7s) to the video as well.  The 2006 game starts at 2:06.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is The Elder Scrolls IV: Oblivion.

Your image is from the first person view, but the elements of the HUD match.

Health, mana and stamina bars are at the lower left, followed by icons for the current weapon and spell. Next is the compass with nearby locations. The center icon at the bottom of the screen is indicating that the player can level up. The two icons at the upper right indicate ongoing magical effects.

Comparison image from an [IGN Review](http://ca.ign.com/articles/2007/03/26/the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion-review)

[image]

Comment: Note: first person view is the intended view for the Elder Scroll games.

Comment: @Nzall What do you mean? Elder scrolls games look totally natural in third person, beautiful walking and jumping animations...  /s

Comment: Bethesda added both modes to suit both playstyles. It's up to you whether to play in first or third person (or even to alternate between)

Comment: Originally, FP was the only way to play.  TP was added at a later date if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @NZKshatriya *TES: Arena* and *TES II: Daggerfall* were both first person only. The spinoff game *An Elder Scrolls Legend: Battlespire* was also first person only, but the next spinoff *TES Adventures: Redguard* was third person only. *TES III: Morrowind* was the first main game to allow both first and third person, although the game defaults to first person and can't even be switched to third person until about ten minutes (since you are walking around but haven't chosen your race and whatever yet). Based on that, I think it was definitely intended to be played in first person.

Comment: If it wasn't for melee I think they'd just be completely first person. Ranged weapons and spells make far more sense that way.